# In c++ std::cout<<nullptr program crash but in c printf("%s",NULL) not

Tags: c++, c, null, strstr, nullptr

**C++**

**1.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main()
{
    char s1[20]="bonapart",s2[]="boy",*k;

    std::cout<<"hey";

    k=strstr(s1,s2);
    std::cout<<k;
    
    std::cout<<"bye";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hey
```

so why program is crashing here

**2.**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{

    std::cout<<"hey";
    
    std::cout<<nullptr;
    
    std::cout<<"hey";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::nullptr_t')
```

why this error ?

**C**

**1.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[20]="bonapart",s2[]="boy",*k;
    
    printf("Hey");
    k=strstr(s1,s2);
    printf("%s",k);
    
    printf("bye");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hey(null)bye
```

works fine here

**2.**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hey");
    
    printf("%s",NULL);
    
    printf("bye");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hey(null)bye
```

works fine.

So why in C++ code is crashing at runtime due to null string though C works fine by just putting null for null string.

Comment: When printing a string, the pointer passed will be dereferenced. A null pointer can't be dereferenced, attempting to do so will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also, There are two overloads for the `<<` "output" operator that can take a pointer: 1) The C-style null-terminated string output operator; And 2) The generic pointer output operator. When you use `nullptr` which one should be used?

Comment: "So why in C++ code is crashing at runtime due to null string though C works fine by just putting null for null string." Because both of them have undefined behaviour.

Comment: `std::cout << static_cast<void const*>(nullptr);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks first of all, in both c and c++ null and nullptr can't be defrenced and in both languages they will invoked undefined behaviour ? and also printing on output screen "(null)" in C language is part of undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and also printing on output screen "(null)" in C language is part of undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't understand your 2nd comment properly will you please put some extra light on that

Comment: [Output streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) have multiple overloads for the "output" operator `<<`. [Some which is used for strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), and [some which are used for other things](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). One of the string overloads take a pointer as argument, and so does one of the others. `nullptr` can be used for *both* types of pointers. But which one should be used? That's the *ambiguity* error you get, the compiler can't pick one or the other.

Comment: It would not be ambiguous if you used a more modern compiler which supports the C++17 standard, as it has specified an overload for `<<` that explicitly takes a `nullptr_t` argument, which is the type of `nullptr`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got  it now, Thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "When printing a string, the pointer passed will be dereferenced. A null pointer can't be dereferenced, attempting to do so will lead to undefined behavior"  this valid for both C and C++ or  for just C++?

Comment: Yes. Null pointer can't be dereferenced in neither C nor C++. The behavior you're seeing in the C program is because of an *implementation specific extension*. IIRC it's not mandated by the C specification, and passing a null pointer might as well crash.

Comment: and it does often crash as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: thanks @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   char  a=3, *p ; 
 p=nullptr ; 
 std::cout<<"hey"<<p<<"bye";    this also crashing so why crashing here is no concept of derfrencing and if I am making float type it print out hey0bye why not 0.000000

Comment: @AbhishekMane That code calls one of the string overloads of the `<<` operator for `p`. This overload will dereference the pointer to print the supposedly null-terminated string. That will not work since `p` is a null pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got it thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   printf("%f",2);   printf("%f",0);   printf("%f",NULL);  all these 3 statements have output is 0.000000 (in context of C ) why this  ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane In most systems a null pointer is equivalent to the integer value zero. In C the macro `NULL` is often defined as `((void *) 0 )`.

Comment: Also note that to print a pointer (which `NULL` really is) then you need the `%p` format specifier. Mismatching format specifier and argument type (like using `%d` for a pointer) really leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230525/discussion-between-abhishek-mane-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry I don't know that you do not do chat just stack Overflow notify me that avoid extended discussion in comments so. let it be

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  thanks I got it, printf("%f",0) -> 0.000000 this is case of undefined behaviour right ? and also I checked printf("%p",NULL) it works fine and output is 0000..... total 16 digits with zeroes is there any reason for these 16 digits regarding NULL just curious ?

Comment: Yes it's UB (Undefined Behavior) because of the mismatchinbg format and argument. And 16 digits because you're on a 64-bit system with 64-bit pointers (16 hexadecimal digits).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got it , Thanks for all help I really mean it.

Comment: No problem, that's why we're here! :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but in C++ int *a=nullptr; cout<<a ; output is 0 just one bit but in C  int *a=NULL; printf("%p",(void*)a); it is 0000.....16 bits  so why these differences even pointer take 8 byte memory in both cases ?

Comment: `int a` or `int* a`? There's a big difference. Also, output though a C++ stream with `<<` is going to be different from `printf`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry I made writing mistake  int *a=nullptr;  only

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude https://stackoverflow.com/q/66998504/11862989 can you please answer this question

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://stackoverflow.com/q/67772282/11862989 can you answer this question please