# Ternary operator, if I avoid writing ' expression 2 ' it works but if I not write 'expression 3 ' it gives an error

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int a=4,b,c;
    a==3 ? : b=a*a ;     // Works fine
    a==4 ? c=a*a : ;     // ERROR Expected Primary expression before ;
}
```

- **1st conditional statement**

  I did not write '**Expression 2**' but it will not produce error
- **2nd Conditional statement**

  I did not write '**Expression 3**' it gives an error

so why it is differentiating in '**Expression 2**' and '**Expression 3**' ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is supported in GNU C/C++ and is called the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator). It's not allowed in standard C++ (e.g. MSVC++ doesn't support it).

It's described in the [official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)

> 6.8 Conditionals with Omitted Operands
> The middle operand in a conditional expression may be omitted. Then if the first operand is nonzero, its value is the value of the conditional expression.
>
> Therefore, the expression
>
> x ? : y
>
> has the value of x if that is nonzero; otherwise, the value of y.
>
> This example is perfectly equivalent to
>
> x ? x : y
>
> In this simple case, the ability to omit the middle operand is not especially useful. When it becomes useful is when the first operand does, or may (if it is a macro argument), contain a side effect. Then repeating the operand in the middle would perform the side effect twice. Omitting the middle operand uses the value already computed without the undesirable effects of recomputing it.

Comment: Thanks. This is something new about the possible ternary operator for me.

Comment: https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=402

Comment: What the documentation doesn't make clear is that `?:` is a binary operator. Nothing is "omitted". It's just that the syntax they chose makes it _look_ like the ternary operator with the middle operand left out. `foo = x ?: y;` could just as well had been `foo = x ?? y;` or even `foo = x || y;` where `x`, if evaluated to `true` in a boolean context, would be assigned to `foo` as `x` and not as `true` (as it will in  C++). If they ever bring this operator into the standard (which would be nice), I'd prefer something like `foo = x ||| y;` (to not break anything).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'd prefer `foo = x ?? y;` (JavaScript, TypeScript) but that's just my opinion. I think I've read it's bad practice and should be avoided but I'm not able to find the source and I don't remember the reason. `?:` is a binary operator that can contain spaces `? :`.

Comment: Yeah, that space ... I think they made that valid just to be able to mess with peoples heads :-) In perl it's `$foo = $x || $y;` and there I've used it extensively. I personally think it's a nice little operator.

Comment: `?:` is not a single token in this case.  Syntactically, what you have a is a `?` token followed by a `:` token.  The extension permits omitting the operand that would normally be required between them, which is why it permits whitespace between `?` and `:`.