# problems with Move constructor and Move overloaded assignment operator?

Tags: c++, move, destructor, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Mostly all things explained by fredoverflow(user 237K Rep.) in his Two answers

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/11862989
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/11862989

But while implementing Move constructor and overloaded Move Assignment operator(`OMAO`)( I am using these short form throughout the question ) I am facing some problem that I will put here.

Also there is another answer by user Greg Hewgill (user with 826K Rep.)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106136/11862989his
I am Quoting him,

> Suppose you
> have a function that returns a substantial object then an ordinary C++
> compiler will create a temporary object for the result of multiply(),
> call the copy constructor to initialize r, and then destruct the
> temporary return value. Move semantics in C++0x allow the "move
> constructor" to be called to initialize r by copying its contents, and
> then discard the temporary value without having to destruct it.

I will also refer this in question.

okay Now I will start

## Code

### .cpp

```
#include"34_3.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstring>

A::A()                                       // O arg ctor
{
    std::cout<<"0 arg constructor\n";
    p=0;
    s=nullptr;
        
}

A::A(int k1,const char *str)                 // 2 arg ctor
{
    std::cout<<"2 arg constructor\n";
    
    p=k1;
    s=new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(s,str);
    
}

A::A(const A &a)                             // copy ctor
{
    std::cout<<"copy constructor\n";
    
    p=a.p;
    s=new char[strlen(a.s)+1];
    strcpy(s,a.s);
    
}

A::A(A &&a)                                   // Move ctor
{
    std::cout<<"Move constructor\n";
    
    p=a.p;
    s=new char[strlen(a.s)+1];
    strcpy(s,a.s);
    a.s=nullptr;
    
}


A& A::operator=(const A &a)                 // Overloaded assignement opeator `OAO`
{
    std::cout<<"overloade= operator\n";
    
    p=a.p;
    s=new char[strlen(a.s)+1];
    strcpy(s,a.s);
    return *this;
    
}


A& A::operator=(A &&a)                        // `OMAO`
{
    std::cout<<"Move overloade = operator\n";
    
    p=a.p;
    s=new char[strlen(a.s)+1];
    strcpy(s,a.s);
    a.s=nullptr;
    return *this;
    
}

A::~A()                                       // Dctor
{
    delete []s;
    std::cout<<"Destructor\n";
    
}

void A::display()
{
    std::cout<<p<<" "<<s<<"\n";
    
}
```

### .h

```
#ifndef header
#define header

struct A
{
    private:
        int p;
        char *s;
    public:
        A();                            //  0 arg ctor
        A(int,const char*);             //  2 arg ctor
        A(const A&);                    //  copy ctor
        A(A&&);                         //  Move ctor
        
        A& operator=(const A&);         // `OAO`
        A& operator=(A&&);              // `OMAO`
        
        ~A();                           // dctor
        
        void display(void);
        
};
#endif
```

I am putting few main functions and their outputs here so I can discuss the problem easily.

### 1_main

```
A make_A();
int main()
{
    A a1=make_A();
    
    a1.display();
    
}
A make_A()
{
    A a(2,"bonapart");
    return a;
    
}
```

#### Output

```
2 arg constructor
2 bonapart
Destructor
```

1. why it is not executing Move constructor but if I commented out Move constructor definition in .cpp file and declaration in .h file then it give error `[Error] no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)'` and if I use this `A a1=std::move(make_A());` then Move constructor calls, So why this happening ?
2. Why destructor for object `a` in make_A() function is not running ?

#### 2_main()

```
A make_A();
int main()
{
    A a1;
    a1=make_A();
    
    a1.display();
    
}
A make_A()
{
    A a(2,"bonapart");
    return a;
    
}
```

#### Output

```
0 arg ctor
2 arg ctor
Move overloade = operator
copy ctor
Dctor
Dctor
2 bonapart
Dctor
```

1. Now here copy constructor and destructor runs for temporary object created due to return *this from Move overload = operator function. According to Greg Hewgill statement `C++ 0x` allows Move constructor to be called to initialize by copying it's contents and then discard the temporary value without having to destruct it. I am using `C++11` but still initializing is done by creating temporary object, copy constructor.
2. I am not getting  for which object that 2nd destructor is running?

#### 3_main

fredoverflow (user 237K Rep.) kept return type of Move overloaded operators `A&` but I think it is wrong.

```
A make_A();
int main()
{
    A a1,a2;
    a2=a1=make_A();
    
    a1.display();
    a2.display();
    
}
A make_A()
{
    A a(2,"bonapart");
    return a;
    
}
```

#### Output

```
[Error] prototype for 'A& A::operator=(A&&)' does not match any in class 'A'
```

so I feel return type should be `A&&` or `A` but `A&&` too give error `[ERROR] can't bind a lvalue to a&&`

so return type must be `A`, am I right ?

#### 4

In Move constructor and Move overloaded = operator I used `a.s=nullptr;` This statement is always used in Move semantics fredoverflow(user) explained something like "now the source no longer owns the object it" but I am not getting it. Because if I did not write this statement still no problem everything works fine. please explain this point

Comment: *I am not getting for which object that 2nd dctor is running?* -- Print the value of `this`, not just `"ctor"` or `"dtor"`.  The `this` value will give you a much better indication of what object is printing those lines.

Comment: In your "move" constructor and assignment operators you have the statement `a.s=nullptr;`. That will lead to a *leak* since the memory allocated for `a` is not longer free'd. You should "move" the pointers instead, not reallocate and copy (that's what the copy constructor and assignment operators do). For example by just swapping the pointers: `std::swap(s, a.s);` (But remember to initialize `s` to `nullptr` *first* in the constructor).

Comment: do you want an anw or an answer ? ;) Please don't use abbreviations all over the place

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's printing address of object `a1` by which we called Move overloaded operator but what that means

Comment: 1_main Move constructor is not executed due to copy elision. Try either `A a1(std::move(make_A()));`  or `A a1=std::move(make_A());` to make it called explicitly

Comment: @nhatnq you are right but now extra destructor is also running, for whom it is running now ?

Comment: try to start by just using one definition of A and understanding it first.  1_main: Are you compiling for debug with no optimizations? 2_main: what's even capable of printing dctor?  3_main: syntax for move = operator is a2=std::move(a1)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah you are right. I did not checked your comment at that time. I think I don't have clear understanding of Move semantics. I read all by fredoverflow(user 237k Rep) on Move semantics. I am not getting  why destructor is not running for object `a` which is declared in `Make_A()` fun. some guy commented me that is extension of life, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision NRVO happens but I did not understand it. and you mentioned about `swap` there is no another way to do this ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `A a1=std::move(make_A())`  will call the Move constructor but  why `A a1=make_A(); not calls the Move constructor but actually it stores that value when I check it by display function. I listened about `std::move` first time can you explain it please or give some link where it explained.

Comment: You should just ask your question without all the preamble and waffle about other questions and answers

Comment: @M.M Noted. From next time I will take care of this.

Comment: One question per question please. Also, the first "sub-question" is a duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization/12953150#12953150)

Comment: @JaMiT Then for every Question I have to put this lengthy code of .h file and .cpp file

Comment: @AbhishekMane First off, so what? Are you incapable of copy-paste-edit? Second, no, you do not have to put this lengthy code in each question. You should instead come up with simpler, more focused code. For example, your questions do not refer to `display()`, so drop that. This allows dropping all data members from `A`, which in turn makes the member functions so simple that they might as well be defined inline. *Poof!* No more .cpp file.

Comment: @JaMiT right. I will do it from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `A` has several issues:

- Your assignment operator don't handle self assignment and leak:

  ```
  A& A::operator=(const A& a)
  {
      std::cout<<"overload operator=\n";
      if (this != &a)
      {
          p = a.p;
          delete[] s;
          s = new char[strlen(a.s) + 1];
          strcpy(s, a.s);
      }
      return *this;
  }
  ```
- Your move doesn't move but copy:

```
A::A(A&& a) : p(a.p), s(a.s)
{
    a.s = nullptr;
    std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
}

A& A::operator=(A&& a)
{
    std::cout << "Move overload operator=\n";

    if (this != &a) {
        p = a.p;
        delete [] s;
        s = a.s;
        a.s = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Now, about

```
A make_A()
{
    A a(2,"bonapart"); // Constructor
    return a;
}
```

There are several scenario because of potential copy elision (NRVO)
(gcc has flag as `-fno-elide-constructors` to control that)

if NRVO apply, then `a` is construct "in-place" so no extra destruction/move happens;

else there is a move constructor and the destruction of `a`.

```
A make_A()
{
    A a(2,"bonapart"); // #2 ctor(int const char*)
    return a; // #3 move (elided with NRVO)
} // #4 destruction of a, (elided with NRVO)

int main()
{
    A a1; // #1: default ctor
    a1 = // #5: Move assignment (done after make_A)
      make_A(); // #6: destructor of temporary create by make_A

    
    a1.display();
} // #8: destructor of a1
```

With NRVO

```
default ctor
ctor(int const char*)
move assignment
destructor
display
destructor
```

without NRVO (`-fno-elide-constructors`)

```
default ctor
ctor(int const char*)
move ctor
destructor
move assignment
destructor
display
destructor
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f840632094430f0)

For

```
A a1,a2;
a2 = a1 = make_A();
```

`a1 = make_A();` use move assignment.
`a2 = (a1 = make_A())` use copy assignment as move assignment returns (correctly) `A&`

> 4
> In Move constructor and Move overloaded = operator I used `a.s=nullptr;` This statement is always used in Move semantics fredoverflow(user) explained something like "now the source no longer owns the object it" but I am not getting it. Because if I did not write this statement still no problem everything works fine. please explain this point

Your issue is that you do copy instead of move.

If you do `s = a.s;` instead of the copy

```
s = new char[strlen(a.s) + 1];
strcpy(s, a.s);
```

then both `this->s` and `a.s` would point of same data, and both `this` and `a` would free the (same) memory in their destructor -> double free error.

`a.s = nullptr;` would fix that issue.

Comment: Thanks, I am understanding your answer it will take some time as to understand I have to learn some new points you mentioned in your answer. I mentioned this comment to know you that I am checking answer but not ignoring. okay.

Comment: Just a note: I believe any assignment operator requiring a self-assignment check to work “correctly” is still broken! The example above is no exception: if the allocation after `delete[] s;` fails with an exception, the object is left in an unrecoverable state. I’d generally recommend leveraging the copy constructor, `swap()` and, destructor: `A(a).swap(*this);` If you pass the parameter by value it is even easier: `A& operator=(A a)( a.swap(*this); return *this; }`. In this case `swap` is simple (`void swap(A& a){ std::swap(a.s, this->s); }`) but I’d still keep the pattern.

Comment: @Jarod42 __1.__ with NRVO you displayed output the 4th statement in that output is destructor for whom that destructor is running ? is it running for rvalue returned by `a` from `make_A()` function. Also you mentioned something like `life time extension` can you put some light on this .

Comment: @Jarod42 __2.__ regarding returned type of Move overloaded Assignment operator. I got your point `A&` works fine. So which one is good or which one should I prefer `A` or `A&` as both work perfectly.

Comment: @Jarod42 __3.__ I think you missed my 1st Question. can you explain it please. why that is happening ?

Comment: @Jarod42 __4.__ `without NRVO (-fno-elide-constructors)` that you displayed output. on which compiler like C++11, C++14, C++17 I should check to get that output.

Comment: I numbered with `#n` to show from where display happens. #4 is the destruction of local variable `a`. lifetime extension is when you have `const T& ref = temporary;`, then temporary is destroyed when `ref` goes out of scope instead of at the end of statement. Prefer `A& operator=`. Q1 about "missing" constructor/destructor is because of NRVO. (Prefer to focus on one question by question BTW). You can see version in Demo. Notice that C++17 has some required elision (for RVO) which are optional in previous version.

Comment: @Jarod42 see `A a1; a1=make_A();` so that is actually like ` a1.operator=(make_A() );` right. so `make_A()` returning rvalue of local variable in it's function not reference. That rvalue is passed as an argument and collected by rvalue reference ` A  &&a` in Move overloaded=operator. Now after `return *this` statement in Move overload=operator  again control back to main function so when will actually `A &&a` get out of scope. Here I feel it's going out of scope before the end of statement, am I right ? again one point, is temporary value loose his own identity after it get rvalue reference ?

Comment: @Jarod42 loose it's identity in sense it's destruction totally depend upon reference even that reference scope ends before that statement where that temporary object is present. and you mentioned `const T& ref=temporary;` I think it should be `T&&` as we are referring to rvalue.

Comment: In regular case (no lifetime extension)`/*A val =*/ makeA();` creates a temporary which is destroyed at end of full expression (at `;`). With lifetime extension `const A& a = makeA();` or `A&& a = makeA();` the temporary is destroyed when `a` goes out of scope.

Comment: @Jarod42 but `a1=make_A()` the rvalue returned by `make_A()` function is referred by rvalue reference in __Move overload=operator.__  so here also we are referring to rvalue, aren't we ? and sorry if  my doubts seem silly to you but  it's very hard to digest them.

Comment: `A::operator=(A&& rhs)` will indeed "use" the temporary (`rhs` is a (rvalue) reference, so doesn't call destructor) but (moved-from) temporary cretaed by `makeA` would call its destructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 but you mentioned that when `rvalue reference` get out of scope then temporary is destroyed.

Comment: With lifetime extension (which doesn't happen with function parameter).

Comment: @Jarod42 in Q 1_main I updated little bit if I use this `A a1=std::move(make_A());` instead of `A a1=Make_A();`  then Move constructor. Why this is happening  and I am not understanding anything about `NRVO` and `(-fno-elide-constructors)` can you explain it please elaborately or give link where it  explained properly.

Comment: @Jarod42 please do reply

Comment: @Jarod42 I am Accepting your answer and giving bounty as you covered most of my doubts. I think I did not have sufficient knowledge of Move semantics when I will get enough time I will read it thoroughly. let it be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1_main: Move constructor is not executed due to copy elision
The extra destructor is observed after the swap is done, the temporary object is destroyed.

2_main: Same observation as in 1_main where move operator is called

3_main: The error is seen because you're using a low version of compiler. might need to specify -std=c++11

4: `a.s=nullptr` is not a case of move as you're allocating new memories and do kind of copy. For example

```
A::A(A &&a)                                   // Move ctor
{
    std::cout<<"Move constructor\n";       
    p=a.p;
    s=a.s;
    a.s=nullptr; 
    a.p=0;
}
```

Comment: Constructors do not have return types

Comment: the commented-out lines should be in , otherwise destruction of old object will leave dangling pointer in the new

Comment: @M.M I got it but wanted to leave an undefined behavior so commented them out ,will undo them